# Difference between close and shutdown a node in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Having a cluster with a single node :

```
Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().loadConfigSettings(true).node();
```

What is the difference betwwen

```
node.close();
```

and

```
node.client().admin().cluster().prepareNodesShutdown().execute().actionGet();
```

?

What's the recommended method to gracefully shutdown the node/cluster from java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both mentioned operations have the same effect. The difference is, potentially, the nodes they affect.

With `node.close()` you close your own node, that you started from your application, which can either be the only node you have if you embed the elasticsearch cluster in your application, or just a client node that connects to an external cluster through java api (transport port).

Using the [nodes shutdown api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-shutdown.html) you can effectively shutdown remote nodes, potentially multiple nodes and the whole cluster as well in a single operation. As a result, each node in the context of the command will be closed, again calling the `close` method.

Also, both commands gracefully close nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> If you deign to use shutdown() on unconnected datagram sockets, it
>   will simply make the socket unavailable for further send() and recv()
>   calls (remember that you can use these if you connect() your datagram
>   socket.)
>
> It's important to note that shutdown() doesn't actually close the file
>   descriptor—it just changes its usability. To free a socket descriptor,
>   you need to use close().

- [Source 1](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#closedown)
- [Source 2](http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/Socket-4/What_is_the_difference_between_close_and_shutd.html)

However, as far as ***Elasticserach*** goes, there API does not mention any difference in particular (just a [Client example](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html) and a [Nodes Shutdown example](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-shutdown.html)).  These are the common defined differences.  It may be best to contact their development (there is an option at the bottom of the website) to get a more detailed explanation on the implementation of their library.

I'd recommend using the `node` to access the cluster, then loop the cluster and individually close all nodes.  However, this depends on what you ***really*** want.

Comment: I mentioned what I really want in the question : 'gracefully shutdown the node'

Comment: I've usually seen `close()` used with a grace time period.  I'm not sure if ***Elasticsearch***'s `Node` class allows for giving a grace period (usually in milliseconds), but if so, you should give a grace period to allow a graceful close/shutdown.